# How to use validation annotation in setter method with Jackson

Tags: java, validation, jackson

I know that I could put the annotations on age field.

But I want to validate age in setAge method, here is my code:

```java
class UserController {

    @PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity partialUpdate(@RequestBody @Validated UserDTO userDTO) {
        return userService.partialUpdate(userDTO);
    }
}
```

```java
public class UserDTO {

    private String username;

    private Integer age;

    public void setAge(@Min(0) @Max(100) Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

It's valid when I give age=101, seems the validations not work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use the Validator to check whether you class is valid.

If you are creating a object of `UserDTO`.

```
UserDTO user = new UserDTO("My Name", 101);
```

Then perform the following

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<SomeEntity>> errors = validator.validate(user);
```

Then based on your requirement do the necessary things like notify client what was the wrong field, log them. If empty then it seems like everything is valid and proceed further.

```
if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(errors)){
  throw new ConstraintViolationException(errors);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a solution with using javax.validation annotations